# node.js query Redis result from last query in one program?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using Redis to store data. First, I query e.g. smembers(5). I get the result e.g. 1, 6. And then I want to query smembers(1), smembers(6) as well. Does anybody know is that possible to implement it in one program using node.js? I know it can be implemented in multiple program. Then it would be inconvenient.

```
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> smembers 5
1) "1"
2) "6"
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> smembers 1
1) "2"
2) "3"
3) "4"
4) "6"
5) "7"
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> smembers 6
1) "5"
```

Comment: can you paste the data example here?

Comment: Sure. I take an example: sadd 1(key) 2 3 4 6 7, sadd 2(key) 19 20, sadd 3(key) 4 17 18. sadd.....

Comment: So if I query smembers(1), then I want to get smembers(2), smembers(3)....as well

Comment: Actually I am storing a graph. node and adjacency node.